# Database query builder using conditional clause for boolean column

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I made a frontend filter component to filter returned results from the database, the issue I m having if I want to filter a db column with boolean value as it executes for true value but don't do anything for the false value as below:
[image: filter component]

As it is stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

> The when method only executes the given closure when the first argument is true. If the first argument is false, the closure will not be executed.

Table migration includes:

```
$table->boolean('featured')->default(false);
```

Model:

```
protected $casts = [
   'featured' => 'boolean',
   'images' => 'json',
   'files' => 'json',
];
```

I am using `livewire` in the component class, I get the query:

```
public function getRowsQueryProperty()
{
    $query = Post::query()
    ->when($this->filters['status'], fn ($query, $status) => $query->where('status', $status))
    ->when($this->filters['category'], fn ($query, $categoryId) => $query->where('category_id', '=', $categoryId))
    ->when($this->filters['featured'], fn ($query, $featured) => $query->where('featured', $featured))
    ->when($this->filters['date-min'], fn ($query, $date) => $query->where('publish_date', '>=', Carbon::parse($date)))
    ->when($this->filters['date-max'], fn ($query, $date) => $query->where('publish_date', '<=', Carbon::parse($date)))
    ->when($this->filters['search'], fn ($query, $search) => $query->where('title', 'like', '%'. $search . '%')->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' . $search . '%'));

    return $this->applySorting($query);
}
```

The blade component:

```
<x-form.input-group label="Featured" for="featured" :error="$errors->first('editing.featured')">
                    <x-form.select wire:model="editing.featured" id="featured">
                        <option value="" disabled>Select Featured Status...</option>
                        <option value="true">True</option>
                        <option value="false">False</option>
                    </x-form.select>
                </x-form.input-group>
```

Thanx for any help,

Comment: Try instead setting option values to true/false, using 1/0.

Comment: no need because I already have `protected $casts = ['featured' => 'boolean', 'images' => 'json', 'files' => 'json'];` but I did that same thing.

Comment: The value from option is always TEXT. And the text "true" and also text "false" will be interprated in bool as true. `(bool) "false"` is `true`. Becouse not empty text is true always.
But if you use 0/1 then, `(bool) "0"` will be false.

Comment: As I said I did that too but that didn't change anything, if you read the documentation you will find >The when method only executes the given closure when the first argument is true. If the first argument is false, the closure will not be executed. I need a way to return true or false values by the filter